# How can I store grouped data in seperate data frames in a nested for-loop

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, for-loop

I already have a dictionary of data frames, I would like to loop over each data frame of the dictionary and and group them based on the column named: Size and then store for each group of the data in a new data frames B.
My problem is: for each iteration, B will be replaced by a newer data frame. I would like to have all the data frames for all possible groups. Anyone has any ideas on how to do that?

Small example:

```
data = {'Name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack','Kody','Kim'], 'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18,6,6],'Size':['M','M','L','S','S','M']} 
data2={'Name':['Jason', 'Damon', 'Ronda', 'Kylie','Ron','Harry'], 'Age':[20, 12, 11, 13,6,5],'Size':['L','M','L','M','L','L']} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
df2=pd.DataFrame(data2)
A={}
A[0] = df
A[1]=df2
B={}
for x in range(0,2):
    A[x]=A[x].groupby(["Size"])
    KeysA=list(A[x].groups.keys())
    display(len(KeysA))
    for z in range(0, len(KeysA)):
        B[z]= A[x].get_group(str(KeysA[z]))
```

I want to have this output: (see picture),
with my code the data frames are overwritten with each iteration. So I have in the end three data frames instead of five.

[image: I want to have this output]

Comment: please supply us with a minimal reproducible example if you want us to help with your code! We need expected output and the dataframes you have

Comment: @Ironkey please check the edit I made for my question, I added a small example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Name': ['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack', 'Kody', 'Kim'], 'Age': [20, 21, 19, 18, 6, 6],
        'Size': ['M', 'M', 'L', 'S', 'S', 'M']}
data2 = {'Name': ['Jason', 'Damon', 'Ronda', 'Kylie', 'Ron', 'Harry'], 'Age': [20, 12, 11, 13, 6, 5],
         'Size': ['L', 'M', 'L', 'M', 'L', 'L']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
A = {}
A[0] = df
A[1] = df2
B = {}
new_df = pd.concat(A.values())
groups = new_df.groupby(["Size"])
for group in groups:
    B[group[0]] = group[1]

for k, v in B.items():
    print(f"{k}: {v}")
```

output:

```
L:     Name  Age Size
2  krish   19    L
0  Jason   20    L
2  Ronda   11    L
4    Ron    6    L
5  Harry    5    L
M:     Name  Age Size
0    Tom   20    M
1   nick   21    M
5    Kim    6    M
1  Damon   12    M
3  Kylie   13    M
S:    Name  Age Size
3  jack   18    S
4  Kody    6    S
```

For 5 Dataframes (in a list) do this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Name': ['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack', 'Kody', 'Kim'], 'Age': [20, 21, 19, 18, 6, 6],
        'Size': ['M', 'M', 'L', 'S', 'S', 'M']}
data2 = {'Name': ['Jason', 'Damon', 'Ronda', 'Kylie', 'Ron', 'Harry'], 'Age': [20, 12, 11, 13, 6, 5],
         'Size': ['L', 'M', 'L', 'M', 'L', 'L']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
A = {}
A[0] = df
A[1] = df2
B = []
for key, value in A.items():
    groups = value.groupby(["Size"])
    for group in groups:
        B.append(group[1])

for x in B:
    print(x)
```

output:

```
    Name  Age Size
2  krish   19    L
   Name  Age Size
0   Tom   20    M
1  nick   21    M
5   Kim    6    M
   Name  Age Size
3  jack   18    S
4  Kody    6    S
    Name  Age Size
0  Jason   20    L
2  Ronda   11    L
4    Ron    6    L
5  Harry    5    L
    Name  Age Size
1  Damon   12    M
3  Kylie   13    M
```

Comment: Hi @D-E-N thanks for your answer. I would actually like to have seperate data frames  grouped by size as shown in the picture. And in reality, I have around 26 data frames so the code should work for large numbers of data frames.

Comment: i added some code for 5 dataframes, but i think i do not understand your problem correct, sry. (The results are grouped Series in a list/dictionary)

Comment: thanks :) the code for 5 data frames worked perfectly :) @D-E-N